# Why "perfectly"?

Tags: usage, british-english

British English native have translate this sentence in Croatian:

> Growing vegetables has always been a normal pursuit in the countryside and in towns.

like this in English:

> Growing vegetables has always been a **perfectly** normal pursuit in the countryside and in towns.

Why "perfectly"?

Comment: Your former sentence, you've translated it from Croatian yourself. So I think the question boils down to why machine translation has inserted a "perfectly" out of nowhere? AFAIK, the answer to that is "because".

Comment: Including "perfectly" simply *emphasises* how normal it is.

Comment: This really isn't related to British English. This is a standard usage in American English, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saying something is "perfectly normal" is a response to an (often unspoken) argument or expectation that some activity is *not* normal.  For example:

> I don't know what you're staring at.  Wearing galoshes on a sunny day is *perfectly normal*.
>
> People say she's odd, but she thinks eating dessert before dinner is *perfectly normal*.

I can't tell from the context of your sentence whether the use of "perfectly" is justified.  The implication is that growing vegetables is not something you would expect, and you would be surprised that it is a common activity.